# Are there performance gains for useCallback and useMemo with redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, react-usememo, react-usecallback

I've seen a lot of descriptions of why you shouldn't use React's `useCallback` with an empty dependency list (which makes logical sense), but I'm stuck trying to figure out if there are performance gains when using it alongside **redux-toolkit**, when the dependency list includes RT objects. (The application is already performant enough with one user that there's no perceptible difference, so I'm looking to do the "right thing" in the aggregate.)

An example:

```
export const HomeSettings = () => {
  // redux-toolkit
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetUserQuery();
  const [updateUser] = useUpdateUserMutation();

  //useCallback providing an actual optimization here?
  const changeDataFilterOption = useCallback(
    (option: string) => {
      const someObj = someFunc(option, data);
      updateUser(someObj);
    },
    [data, updateUser]
  );

  //useMemo optimizing anything here?
  const itemList = useMemo(() => getListOfThings(data), [data]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingMessage />;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <ErrorLoadingDataMessage />;
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={changeDataFilterOption}>
      onClick is silly here, just illustrating the point
      <div>{itemList}</div>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Using **redux-toolkit** in this way, is there any benefit to memo-izing my callbacks and variables?